# Confusion in printf() output

Tags: java

I am doing some sample practice for formatting string using `format()` and `printf()` methods.
Here is an example, whose output i am confused about please help.

```
int i2= 12345;
//Total length of the argument should be 7 and pad with zeros
System.out.printf(">%0,7d< \N",i2);
```

The output is

```
>012,345<
```

If we see, the length of the argument is six. But does the delimiter is also counted in 
its length. If not then the output should have been this according to me.

```
>001,2345<
```

Please help in clarifying this doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc page for [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) does not mention any special treatment for grouping separators when interpreting the width, it just talks about the number of *characters*:

> *The optional width is a non-negative decimal integer indicating the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.*

Comment: But the formatting instruction is ">%0,7d< \N" not %07D and indeed the comma's and all in the formatted String seems to include into the total width as pointed out by Dan. Please refer to his answer below.Referring to the definition of Formatter, with is a non-negative integer indicating minimum number of character and "," is indeed a character.

Comment: Yes, the `,` adds grouping separators, as Dan points out, but I figured you already knew that based on your question.

Comment: Yup thanks a ton Keppil. Thanks a ton for your detailed reply.

Answer (score 1):

You used a comma and are printing an integer, which means that the '7' is a width and not a precision. The width value refers to the entire formatted string, including leading zeros, spaces, commas, decimals, and negative signs.

Comment: That's correct Dan. I am using with not precision. You precisely answered me that commas and everything is included which is in a formatted String. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

See the [IO Formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) help page. The basic structure is the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW33Y.gif) (click to see).

According to this documentation:

> Width means the minimum width of the formatted value; the value is
>   padded if necessary. By default the value is left-padded with blanks.